# ASCII characters aren't displayed properly on windows

Tags: windows, windows-11, ascii

For some time now I have the issue that I can only use ASCII characters 32 - 126. Any other character is not displayed as it should be. Instead either nothing happens or the unicode replacement character appears. Unicode characters however work fine.

I use windows 11 and the error seems to appear in every program that has some kind of text input, as well as windows text inputs themselves (searchbar, etc.).
My system locale is set to english (us). I have also tried changing the system locale to different languages and disable and reenable the unicode UTF-8 setting.

I appreciate any help or ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Try running DISM / SFC.  This may possibly fix the issue.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ASCII only has characters 0-127. Are you looking for extended ASCII?

Comment: @John Tried that but didn't fix the problem

Comment: @doneal24 Yes extended ascii

Comment: Perhaps the default system font ("Segoe UI" I think) is broken or the registry has been edited to provide a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

> ASCII characters aren't displayed properly on windows

The initial repair is DISM /SFC.

You tried that and it did not solve the problem.

So then the thing to do now is a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

(If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.)

Repair Install Keep Everything should work. It does in most cases.

If not, back up and reinstall Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. Non-printable ASCII character in the range 0-31 get stripped.

This happens when cmd.exe is hosted in
Windows-Terminal 1.15.3466.0
That is the fancy multi tab window for consoles in Windows 11

Windows console host does not have this problem.
You can change the Windows Terminal Settings --> Start --> Default terminal

Answer (score 0):

I know little about this but what worked for me was trying multiple ascii tables, here https://www.ascii-code.com/ you will find them, by default it sends me to "Windows-1252" which in my case didnt help. Tried all of these tables and none of them printed the symbol it was supposed to except one table named "Code page 437" that actually printed everything correctly, so maybe you can try checking if you are using the correct table for your system